# Oracle dbms_java.runjava raise ORA-00904: "SYS"."DBMS_JAVA_MISC"."RUNJAVA": invalid identifier

Tags: oracle

I need to execute a java class outside the db but calling it from a plsql block. As a first attempt I try to do in this way:

```
select dbms_java.runjava(cmdline => 'java -cp /app/oracle/12.2.0/db:/app/oracle/12.2.0/db/jdbc/lib/* test') from dual
```

It raises this exception:

```
ORA-00904: "SYS"."DBMS_JAVA_MISC"."RUNJAVA": invalid identifier
```

Firstable I need to know if I am doing it right or I missunderstand the path (it works without loadjava?) then I would like to know if there is some privs to grant to my schema in order to use the dbms_java package